# To get the answer, you'll have to get the key first

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Below there is a cipher hidden in the text. Read everything very carefully. As far as I know, it will give the necessary hint.

Look for some patterns: Let nobody distract you.

Eventually, you will see the key to decypher the text.

```
3F8vxxtiuPjnnGEn35dHs28mfvxoeStHtjlxmervs01bDUaHbj9MvW2VXy6rSrEvnPEgFBnMeRDZdEIAJwO02AGXObN3b3bdKmCpbUuSklwYeApVi7F8B9ddisvQf0
```

---

Hint:

> You may need to split the text into multiple lines. Which character could you use to do that?

Hint 2:

> There is a hidden hint in the description.

Hint 3:

> After you found the key: The key is used both as a cipher key, as well as an indicator which characters should be used to decypher.

Comment: And to get the key first, you need to get the answer!

Comment: This will probably be very hard to solve, see https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do for some general tips for code puzzles and why this is going to be difficult

Comment: I suppose the [enigmatic-puzzle] tag means the key is somehow encoded into the question title.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I believe it is solvable, because it isn't about cipher in the first place. I have edited the question to clear things up.

Comment: Would be interested to see how a key would even fit, it seems fairly clear to be base62 which doesn't use a key. Anyhow, this will still be pretty hard and a bit of a guessing game, which doesn't usually make for an entertaining puzzle

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil There are a handful of websites that offer to "encrypt your text now!" using some form of modern encryption plus a passphrase of your choice. They will return the encrypted data encoded in base64 to make it possible to copy and paste it. So we have to guess both the passphrase and the specific website used, a double guessing-game.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I have edited the puzzle again, this time including a hidden hint. My other puzzles were solved so very quickly, I had to make this one more difficult. Apparently, too difficult :) Please reconsider the downvote.

Comment: @codewarrior0 I didn't use any website, or any third party tool to create some impossible cypher. I have created the puzzle myself, and tried to be original. I have edited the puzzle to improve this one. Please reconsider the downvote.

Comment: Hi Lezzup, don't feel you have to level up the difficulty of decrypting a cipher - 'More difficult' does not necessarily equate to 'Better puzzle'. In my experience, thinking about the enjoyment the user might get from the solving process and how to increase *that* is usually the key... Keep creating and keep experimenting! :)

Comment: @Lezzup, exactly what Stiv said, it can be hard sometimes to see the puzzle from the eyes and enjoyment of a solver rather than a creator, also for reference, I never downvoted, was just trying to explain why some might, feel its unfair to immediately downvote new users who are experimenting with new puzzle types :)

Comment: Well I found the key (9), but now I need to figure out how to use the key to decipher the text. Unless the key is the answer? The phrase 'to decipher the text' implies I have another step to go... unless it refers to what I did to see the key... not sure...

Comment: @Amoz The key is indeed 9 characters long. That's the first part of the puzzle. There is indeed another step to go. You may post the key as an partial answer, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Part 1 was enjoyable, I upvoted in good faith that part 2 will make sense : ) (totally stuck at the moment). Your edits definitely improved the puzzle, it would have been quite difficult without them.

Comment: Can the hint refer to \n?

Comment: Do any of the hints or clues refer to part 2? Still no idea how to proceed.

Comment: The given hint for multiple lines is for both parts. The key itself is a hint for the next part, and is both used as a key and as a selector of which characters should be used ;)